# How can i include a package that is in a node built in modules (Crypto) in a supabase edge function that use Deno

Tags: serverless, supabase, deno, supabase-database

I am having problems when I deploy the function to supabase, locally the package works correctly using the [node specifiers](https://deno.com/manual@v1.34.3/node/node_specifiers)

`import * as crypton from "node:crypto"`

when i deploy Im getting this error

`error: Uncaught (in promise) Error: Module not found "node:crypto". const ret = new Error(getStringFromWasm0(arg0, arg1));`

I try updating my deno.lock file and updating the supabase function and I can find a solution

Comment: It might be that Supabase doesn’t support node: specifiers.

Comment: Supabase currently doesn't support the `node:` specifier but will do soon. Since the crypto library is built into Deno is there a reason you are using the one from node?